# I need guidance and the right knowledge about the following

Tags: vedas, brahmins, atheism, non-hindu

I am Samyak Marathe. For a very long time I have been denying the existence of god. From the point of view of Hinduism, it means that I don't believe in Brahman, the supreme creator from which everything came into existence. Shiva, Ganesha, and all the gods and goddesses are forms of Brahman. We pray to god (Brahman) through them through idol worship. Nothing is greater than Brahman and after enlightenment everything goes to Brahman.

This is my understanding of the Hindu religion. I don't believe in this and I have tried to convince myself for a long time to believe in god. But I can't live with confirmity of believing in something that everyone around me believes in. So I became a person who says, 'There may or may not be god, but I deny few things in many religions. I deny the idea of god described in the religions.'

Another thing that I oppose is the concept of caste. A person with any surname can become brahmin if they are intellectual. A warrior can have any caste. This is what I like to believe in. But in the modern society the this is not the accepted definition. People find privilege in their caste. They try to take benefits from it. As far as I know manusmriti made it difficult for someone to change caste. It locked the person's caste with his/her birth caste. No longer a persn believes that a person's caste (in hindi jati) is based on the work (karma) they do in their life. But sadly this is not the case. I don't classify myself as a intelligent or intellectualy. Which is why I don't like myself considered as brahmin and I don't consider it anyways. But my family opposes that. Why is caste such an important thing in a persons's life. And why am I entitled to it when I haven't even done anything productive in the society to decide my caste based on my work.

Acoording to Hindu traidition a brahmin is supposed to go from thread ceremony and wear a sacred thread which is a symbol of a new timeline for the person. It means that the person is born again intellectually. He/She is ready to live the life of intelligence, wisdom and guide others. Kind of a degree of the ancient india. Now I don't know if historically this ceremony was held for every person or not because of the system of caste. But today it is considered a ceremony reserved for some castes including brahmins. I don't see every person from different castes living the same life even if they are all hindus.

The current problem with me is that my parents are expecting me to go through this ceremony. I oppose the concept of caste based on birth. I also don't consider myself intellectual enough to go through this ceremony. I don't know everything about it from the point of view of vedas, or people who are like me (non-believers of god). I want to know opinion of others and guidance about what should I do. People live not just India. Most of them who are outside are christians and muslims. They live according to their traditions but still they all are successfull. I am sure there are great people both in India and outside who did great jobs and gave a lot to society but they didn't wear the thread (janeu). Please guide me about this if I am right about the things I said or anything is wrong. Also, I can't do the thread ceremony if it expects me to worship god after I start wearing the thread. Maybe there is god or not. I don't know yet. But one thing that I am sure of is that god described in every religion is not 100% correct. I don't think god would expect things from people to do in order for them to be able to worship him/her.

Thank you.

Comment: Brahman is you, yourself. You don't believe in your own existence?

Comment: > For a very long time I have been denying the existence of god. What exactly are you denying? That there is an all powerful god that will reward and punish you? For that is not Hinduism.

Answer (score 0):

*These are answers to few of more questions.*

Ordinarily, people  envision a desired  goal, which they endeavour to achieve,(because their purpose /aim is quite conceivable). Forasmuch as Ishwara(God) is beyond all possibilities of their conceivability , there isn't  a position for an avg. man thru reasoning either to ascertain or   `disbelieve in Brahman, the supreme creator from which everything came into existence.`

Yet Bhagavad Gita 18.55 may precisely ans. the question.

**BHAKTYA MAAM ABHIJAANAATHI  YAAVAAN YASHCHASMI THATTVATAHA**

**BHAKTYA** Through devotion 
**ABHIJAANAATHI** comes to know of
**MAAM** God (paramatma)
**YAAVAAN** what is God's measure
**YASHCHASMI** who God truly  is, ( in truth)
**THATTVATAHA** truth

**THATHO MAAM THATTVATHO JNATHVA VISHATE THATH ANANTHARAM**
Having known the truth(tattvam) one enters forthwith into God.

It is only when an Upasana/Bhakti upon an aspect(conceivable) of Ishwara , becomes intense enough to translate it into Para bhakti , tattvam/ truth of the Lord is known . It is not possible to say one should know the tattvam , in advance to  do any bhakti.So Sandhyopasana, is path as well, to know the tattvam of God .

> The truths of religion, as God and Soul,
> cannot be perceived by the external senses. I cannot see God
> with my eyes, nor can I touch Him with my hands, and we
> also know that neither can we reason beyond the senses.We may reason
> all our lives, as the world has been doing for thousands of
> years, and the result is that we find we are incompetent to
> prove or disprove the facts of religion. Man has in him the faculty, the
> power, of transcending his intellect even, and that power is in
> every being.  By the practice of Yoga that
> power is aroused, and then man transcends the ordinary limits
> of reason, and directly perceives things which are beyond all
> reason.(Swami Vivekananda)

> The temple, the church, the mosque, the vihara may be different from
> one another. The idol or the symbol in them may not also be the same
> and the rites performed in them may be different. But the Paramatman
> who wants to grace the worshipper, whatever be his faith, is the same.
> The different religions have taken shape according to the customs
> peculiar to the countries in which they originated and according to the
> differences in the mental outlook of the people inhabiting them. The goal
> of all religions is to lead people to the same Paramatman according to the
> different attributes of the devotees concerned. So there is no need for
> people to change over to another faith.
> One big difference between Hinduism and other faiths is that it does not
> proclaim that it alone shows the path to liberation. Our Vedic religion
> alone has not practiced conversion and the reason for it is that our
> forefathers were well aware that all religions are nothing but different
> paths to realise the one and only Paramatman. The Vedas proclaim: "The
> wise speak of the One Truth by different names.”Sri Krsna says in the
> Gita: "**In whatever way or form a man worships me, I increase his faith
> and make him firm and steady in that worship**.”(Pujyasri Chandrashekhara Saraswati Swami ,Kanchi)